# Set Permission-Policy for Vue and NodeJS app

Tags: vue.js, http, http-headers, http-permissions-policy

I have an application that has a VueJs based front end and NodeJs based backend API. The client-side is a SPA and it communicates with API for getting data. Now in a security scan, it is mentioned that the app doesn't have a `Permission-Policy` HTTP header and I would like to add it. I but not sure is there any option I can add in the VueJS and I am confused whether this is something that needs to be added from the front end. From the Node app, it is possible to set the header, but here the pages are not generated from the server-side. It will be helpful if someone can let me know how can I add these headers to the app.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can publish Permissions-Policy header when you sent an initial SPA's HTML code (you have to use some packages or Node.js server facility to publish response header). Even more so scanners do not execute ajax and will not see the pages of your SPA.

But there are some doubts whether it is worth doing it at all.
`Permissions Policy` is a new name of `Feature Policy`, below I will use Feature Policy term, but all of the below also applies to Permissions Policy.

1. Browsers poorly support Feature Policy and [do not support Permissions Policy](https://csplite.com/pp/test397/). Only Chrome supports the `interest-cohort` directive, but you have to set specific flags to enable Permissions Policy support. Feature Policy / Permissions Policy spec still is under development.
2. Feature Policy is rarely published via HTTP header, because it is intended to restrict the capabilities of nested browsing contexts (iframes), and not the main page itself. Therefore it's mostly published via `<iframe allow="..."` attribute for each third-party iframe embedded.
   But the scanners are not aware of this and do not check the `allow=` attribute.
3. Scanners don't know much about real security, they are more focused on visualization baubles like Grade A+ and labels with green/red color. Therefore scanners:

- are not recognize Content Security Policy in meta tag, just in the HTTP header.
- require X-Frame-Options header for any web page despite presence of CSP's `frame-ancestors` derictive and ignore fact that some sites are inbtended to be embedded (widgets, youtube/vimeo video etc.).
- require Feature Policy / Permissions Policy header despite these are not supported or are published by another way.

Mostly scanners results have nothing with real security, all is how to get A+ grade, nothing else (see a relevant thread "[headers manipulatin to get Grade A+](https://metabullet.com/d/479-content-security-policy-of-your-site-blocks-some-resources/54)").

Of course, scanners can draw your attention to some overlooked headlines, but final decision which headers do web-app need to publish is up to you.